# Do Bard spells from the SRD exist in an table format

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, tools, bard

Is there a list of Bard spells, from the SRD in an table format form?

A Google search pulls up lists like various alternative websites, but not in a table format. If I copy and paste them, they paste into Excel, but I get a single column with name and description together.

Columns that I need are only name and description however it would be very nice to have the other things mentioned in the SRD like school and level.

Comment: We do not allow [copyright infringing](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/whats-our-policy-with-answers-advocating-piracy-accidentally-or-not/5383#5383) questions here. Are you interested in SRD only answers?

Comment: That would be fine. I thought specifying core only covered that. I will edit that into the question. @BrianBallsun-Stanton

Comment: I'm sure I could create one for you...it's on my list of things to do anyway...

Comment: What exact columns do you want? If it's just column 1 name, column 2 description and the wiki entry you gave has all the info you want it would be easy for anyone with any Perl or Unix fu to do. (Convert : delimiter into tab, import into Excel)

Comment: It's a long time since I used Excel, but you might just be able to paste that wiki list into a text document, then import it into Excel, giving : (colon) as the field delimiter.

Comment: Or failing that, just paste that wiki list into Word. Run Find and Replace All with : (colon) as the find and tab (actually hit the TAB key or if that fails you should be able to choose with an option like "insert special characters".) Then save it as a plain text (.txt) file and then import into excel as tab delimited list. I'm not giving this as a proper answer as I don't have Windows to test it on, but let me know if it works and I will :-)

Comment: @harlandski you can specify ":" as a delimiter, and it works *fairly* well

Comment: @Aaron I too would like to know what columns you need. [My page](http://rpg20.com/spells.php?area=3&reptype=listbylevel) can already list by class, but I don't know if it's useful to you.

Comment: I hope this isn't stupid, but why do you want it in excel?

Comment: @CataruMoore Easy to sort, edit ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imarvin has a [spell database](http://www.imarvintpa.com/dndlive/) in csv format. It's been a while, but I used it for a similar spread sheet. You'll need to sort by sourcebook, class and level, then just copy what you want into a new file, or delete what you don't want, but shouldn't take but a couple of minutes.

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet is to download the [System Reference Documents](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=130:dad-35) for 3.5, and copy paste them yourself. It's a little labor intensive, but it does mean that you have the formatting just how you like.